# D3 Globe jumps at the start of drag to a different location

Tags: javascript, d3.js, frontend

Good evening! I apologize for my ignorance, but I'm attempting to recreate this D3 element. https://bl.ocks.org/wboykinm/8a87b89f3600a7175f27

If you click to drag or zoom the globe on that page, it jumps to a location in Europe.

What I'm wondering is what needs to change in the sample code to stop that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe* it's `.translate(projection.origin())`

```
//Setup zoom behavior
var zoom = d3.behavior
  .zoom(true)
  .translate(projection.origin())
  .scale(projection.scale())
  .scaleExtent([200, 800])
  .on("zoom", move);
```